# when i use form-create, how to pass vuex data in computed property to data

Tags: vue.js, vuex

my form is dynamically generated by form-create
like

```
<template>
  <form-create :rule='rule' v-model='fApi' :option='options'  />
</template>
    <script>
     export default {
      data() {
        return {
            fApi: {},
            value: {},
            options: {
                submitBtn: false,
                resetBtn: false
            }, 
            props:{ 
              },
            rule: [{
                    type: 'select',
                    field: 'UART_STOPBIT_SELECT',
                    title: 'Stop Selection bit',
                    value: ['1', '2'],
                    options: [{
                            'value': '1',
                            'label': '1 Stop bit',
                            'disabled': false},
                            {
                            'value': '2',
                            'label': '2 Stop bit',
                            'disabled': false}
                            ],
                      props: {
                            placeholder: '',
                            size: 'mini' }
                  },
```

if I write v-model in template, it would be easy to get computed property, but now i need to transfer computed property to data , console shows computed property is undefined, so how to pass vuex data in computed property to data??? I'm confused.

Comment: vuex data can be used via mapGetters or mapState. So they by default will act as a computed property. You can use those in other computed properties as well

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I use https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/forms.html  to handle my form, but when I want to create a  dynamic form based on a json, how to pass vuex data in computed property to data prop, so that I could dynamically create form ?